# Get global variables from map

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have a groovy file for my Jenkins pipeline shared library that would store several keys with default values and be able to call and get the value of individual keys from other functions in different groovy functions such as *test.groovy*. I am not sure how I should or can structure the groovy file.

/vars/settings.groovy

```
def configuration = [
    artifactoryURL: 'artifactory.example.com',                          
    daysToKeep: 14,                                             
    maxRetry: 3 ]
```

/var/test.groovy

```
globalVariables.get('artifactoryURL')   // I would like this to return "artifactory.example.com"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I got this to work as follows:

```
/vars/settings.groovy

#!/usr/bin/groovy
def getConfig() {
def config = [
    artifactoryURL: 'artifactory.example.com',
    daysToKeep: 14,
    maxRetry: 3
]
return config
}

def getValue(name) {
    return config[name]
}


/vars/retrieveValue.groovy

...
echo "value is " + settings.getConfig()
echo "new value is " + settings.getValue('artifactoryURL')
...
```

Output:

```
value is [artifactoryURL:artifactory.example.com, daysToKeep:14, maxRetry:3]
new value is artifactory.example.com
```

Is this correct syntax?
Is there a way to simplify these?

Comment: You could try the Groovy ConfigSlurper.  See http://geekmatt.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-configsluper-instead-of-properites.html.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that link but it seems more work than what I thought I needed by using Groovy Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update in the question works, but not optimal, since the getter is creating a new `config` map everytime. The below should work and should be better. Note that an explicit `getConfig` should not be required, since Groovy automatically creates getters.

```
$ cat vars/settings.groovy

import groovy.transform.Field

@Field static config = [
    artifactoryURL: 'artifactory.example.com',
    daysToKeep: 14,
    maxRetry: 3
]

def getValue(name) {
    return config[name]
}


$ cat vars/retrieveValue.groovy

...
echo "value is " + settings.getConfig()
echo "new value is " + settings.getValue('artifactoryURL')
...
```

Actually `config` should be public and accessible without a getter and `getValue` could be considered redundant with the below approach:

```
$ cat vars/settings.groovy

import groovy.transform.Field

@Field static config = [
    artifactoryURL: 'artifactory.example.com',
    daysToKeep: 14,
    maxRetry: 3
]

def call(name) {
    return config[name]
}


$ cat vars/retrieveValue.groovy

...
echo "value is " + settings.config
echo "new value is " + settings('artifactoryURL')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [config file Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin).

- Setup config file in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Managed Files

  ```
  artifactoryURL ="artifactory.example.com"                                  
  daysToKeep =14                                            
  maxRetry =3
  ```
- In you Jenkinsfile you can call as follow:

  ```
  node {
  stage('configFile Plugin') {

   def myFileId = 'your_file_id'
   configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: myFileId, variable: 'artifactoryURL')]){
     sh "cat ${env.artifactoryURL}"
   }

   }
  }
  ```

Comment: I want to use groovy templates instead of another Jenkins plugin.